# Rails 4 strong parameters ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, mass-assignment, strong-parameters

For some reason in my current controller I am getting ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError even though I believe I am using strong parameters just fine.  Albeit I am using permit! for the time being to permit all model attributes.  See code below, what am I missing

```
class HeuristicsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @heuristics         = Heuristic.order(:name).page params[:page]
        @heuristic      = Heuristic.new
    end

    def create
        @heuristic = Heuristic.new(params[:heuristic])
        if @heuristic.save
            redirect_to action: 'index', :flash => {:success => "New heuristic created!" }
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def new
        @title              = "Heuristic"
        @heuristic          = Heuristic.new
    end

    private

    def heuristic_params
        params.require(:heuristic).permit!      
    end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you did not fully understand the way that strong-params work...

you have a method

```
def heuristic_params
    params.require(:heuristic).permit!      
end
```

and you are not using it

```
Heuristic.new(params[:heuristic])
```

Comment: definitely I'm misunderstanding!  I thought by some Rails magic any reference to params would somehow references MODEL_NAME_params